# How to wait for a function to finish and then call this.next() in onBeforeAction?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In my onBeforeAction method I need to wait for a function to complete and then call this.next().

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    var self = this;

    functionToWait(function () {
        // Success callback
        self.next(); 
    });
});
```

But it appears that onBeforeAction is completed before the function and thus when I am calling self.next() it throws an exception.

---

I have asked a similar question here but my problem is not solved.

[How to make onBeforeAction call wait until a function call inside finishes in meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493809/how-to-make-onbeforeaction-call-wait-until-a-function-call-inside-finishes-in-me)

What needs to happen is that the site needs authentication. And there is a token stored in Session for this purpose. What I would like to achieve is that the token needs to be validated whenever the route has changed. I am trying to do this validation inside onBeforeAction. The new API from iron-router says that I need to call this.next() in this method. But the problem is that the onBeforeAction method finishes running **BEFORE** the validation. And thus in the validation's success callback, calling self.next() will throw an exception.

What I have tried:

1. Write a handler to tell onBeforeAction to wait until validation is completed and then proceed, but the answer from my previous question gave me an infinite loop and I don't know how to solve it.
2. Create a session variable tokenValidated, run the validtion on clientStart. and set it to true in the success call back. And check this variable in the onBeforeAction.

The problem for this solution is that it won't work when you try to refresh the page, for the same reason that onBeforeAction is completed before the validation.

3. Call the onBeforeAction inside the validation success callback directly.

This works after logging in, but when first access the site is not protected.

4. Wait on the Session variable `tokenValidated` directly like this

   this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('token', Session.get('tokenValidated')));

And check if it's ready

```
if (this.ready()) // proceed
```

And it doesn't seem to work either.

The authentication token is stored by this command:

```
Session.setPersistent('authToken');
```

So that it is stored within the localStorage. The behavior I am trying to achieve is:

1. Whenever a new session starts, validate this authToken, and give it state True/Fasle.
2. Check this state in onBeforeAction and proceed accordingly.
3. This state needs to be ready **BEFORE** onBeforeAction.

My problem is that the validation invokes a server method and takes time to return the state, and I cannot find a way to tell onBeforeAction to wait for the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem.

Instead of validating the authentication token in `onBeforeAction`, I do it in client.js like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // Validate authentication token here
    Meteor.call('validateAuthToken', Session.get("authToken"), function (error, result) {
        if (!result) {
            Router.go('/login');
        } else if (!Router.current().route.getName()) {
            // Site init from root, token is validated, direct to notepage
            Router.go('/notepad');
        }
    });
});
```